# Is there a standard notational convention for $L_p$ ($\ell_p$) spaces, norms, and metrics?

Tags: metric-spaces, notation, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

In reading about $L_p$ spaces and $\ell_p$ norms and metrics, I have seen a wide variety of different notations for the same thing.

Is there a standard convention for when to use lowercase $\ell$ vs uppercase $L$, as well as when to use a subscript vs a superscript $p$?

I have seen $L_p$ space, $L^p$ space, $\ell_p^k$ space, $L_p$ metric, $\ell^p$ metric, $\ell^p$ norm, and almost every combination of lowercase, uppercase, subscript, and superscripts possible, in various books and papers.

So far it seems almost random to me and subject to the author's whims, but perhaps there is some guiding principle that most people use here that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Well $L_p$ or $L^p$ refers to a certain class of integrable functions whilst $l_p$ or $l^p$ refers to a class of sequences with specific summability. Notations are varied but few. There seems to be a lot of 'what is the one true answer?' questions lately.

Comment: Subscripts vs. superscripts is a matter of convention, I was taught superscripts but it doesn't matter much either way. Uppercase refers to functions and lowercase refers to sequences, that's universal afaik.